# How far can one go with an app before having to pay for the developer license?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We are using the iAd framework, which I know you need the 99$ developer license in order to be served ads. But you also need the 99$ developer license in order to go live in the AppStore. My question is, how far can one go before having to pay this? I.e. can we do the Testflight for beta testing before having to pay that fee? Or by then will we have to have committed the 99?

The reason I ask is because, if the app store ultimately rejects the app you have effectively flushed the cost of the license down the drain.

Comment: I'm not really clear on your cause and effect here. For argument's sake, let's say you could use Test Flight without paying for the Apple Developer Program. How does that impact whether the app is ultimately rejected during review? You have to pay for ADP to submit the app to be reviewed to go into the App Store in the first place. If your app ends up being rejected, whether or not you used Test Flight is going to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to sign your binary before submitting it for review. In order to sign it, you'll need to have a paid developer account.

This also is valid for TestFlight. From [Apple's page on TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/):

> Apps made available to external testers require a Beta App Review and must comply with the full App Store Review Guidelines before testing can begin. A review is required for new versions of your app that contain significant changes.

Keep in mind that it's not a "license" for one app. There is no real limit on the number of apps you can develop and submit with one developer account.

Comment: How about Testflight? Does it require signing and/or review before that?

Comment: Also wanting to know the answer to the same question ^